# ISP's Customer wants to pass iBGP for his private IP addresses inside his WAN?

Tags: routing, bgp, mpls

Customer has internal networks 10.0.0.0/16, 192.168.0.0/16. Has a network of VPN tunnels, an AT&T MPLS network, and a few Internet (public IP links) from me. I maintain an eBGP AS. He wants to pass us all his iBGP routes from inside his MPLS to us, so we can pass them back to his firewall in the datacenter. I'm a bit confused about him passing us his private stuff, shouldnt his iBGP run only on his gear and not need to be passed to mine, since we are only providing public links? His loopback addresses are private IP range, so I wont even be able to talk to them.

Here's basically how it looks:
[image: Customer Overview Setup]

Comment: You would be correct in telling this customer "H*** NO". If they want a private mesh, then they need to build (or buy) one.

Comment: Sounds like you have a _public AS_ and your customer has a _private AS_.  If you are a provider, you would typically deploy Multiprotocol BGP MPLS VPN.  You might also see [Can I Use BGP as an IGP - Multisite w Redundant Layer 3 MPLS WANs](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35440/can-i-use-bgp-as-an-igp-multisite-w-redundant-layer-3-mpls-wans).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand from your typed text, you/customer want to advertise ibgp routes from his MPLS over eBGP.It is possible and you can do this via Inter-as option C solution 2 with controlled redistribution (or PBR to VPN solution).